# How to directly access the n'th output of a function with multiple outputs in Lua

Tags: python, function, lua, return-value

In Python, one can do the following and access the desired function output:

```
getNthOutput = myFunc(args)[0] #Will get you the first output of a multi-output function in Python
```

How can one do the same thing in Lua? Below is my try which gives me back an error:

```
getNthOutput = myFunc(args)[1] --Get me the first output of a multi-output function in Lua
```

Comment: In Python functions are invoked with `()`, not `[]`. Your example should read: `myFunc()[0]`

Comment: @mhawke sorry my bad. It's fixed now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want the first return value (as per your example) you can do this:

```
first = myFunc(args)
```

If you want an arbitrary return value you can use a table constructor:

```
function myFunc()
    return 1, 2, 'a', 'b'
end

first = ({myFunc()})[1]
print(first)
# 1

n = 4
nth = ({myFunc()})[n]
print(nth)
# b
```

Comment: Note that the table constructor may have issues if the function can return middle `nil` values. You need `select` to handle that robustly (and a function to use that correctly) or `table.pack` in lua 5.2+.

Answer (score 1):

You get an error because multiple return values are not returned as a table. Hence you cannot access any table members using `[]`.

Newer Lua versions provide a function to put the return values in a table safely so you can use index them later.

```
local retVals = table.pack(foo())
local firstValue = retVals[1]
```

or simply

```
table.pack(foo())[1]
```

In older Lua versions there is no function table.pack, but you can simply implement one yourself using a vararg function

```
function myPack(...)
  return {...} -- this only works since Lua 5.1
end
```

I don't expect you to work with something older than 5.1. But if please note that vararg functions worked differently. See the respective Lua reference on Function Definition